# wrap shortcode with square brackets

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

My shortcode function work with or without square brackets. But i want, it only work with square brackets.

**shortcode (I don't want)**

```
itemText num="1" title="This is a title"
```

**shortcode (I want)**

```
[itemText num="1" title="This is a title"]
```

**Here is my code**

```
function shortCode(a, b, c) {
    var split = a.split(" "),
        regex = /(?<=")\w.*?(?=")/g;
    for (var i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
        var pair = split[i].split("=");
        if (pair[0].trim() == b) {
            c = pair[1];
            if (c.match(regex) != null) {
                return String(c.match(regex)).trim()
            } else {
                return false
            }
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

**Example**

```js
function shortCode(a, b, c) {
    var split = a.split(" "),
        regex = /(?<=")\w.*?(?=")/g;
    for (var i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
        var pair = split[i].split("=");
        if (pair[0].trim() == b) {
            c = pair[1];
            if (c.match(regex) != null) {
                return String(c.match(regex)).trim()
            } else {
                return false
            }
        }
    }
    return false
}

$(".test span").each(function () {
    var $this = $(this),
        text = $this.html(),
        mtc = text.toLowerCase(),
        num = shortCode(text, "num"),
        title = shortCode(text, "title");
    if (mtc.match("itemtext")) {
       $this.text(num + " " + title); //expected output: 1 This is a title
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">
    <span>itemText num="1" title="This is a title"</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a shorted code that changes the span only if its content is enclosed in square brackets. The code of the `shortCode()` function is also shortened.

```js
function shortCode(str, attr) {
    let regex = new RegExp('\\b' + attr + '="([^"]*)');
    let m = str.match(regex) || [ null ];
    return  m[1];
}

$(".test span").each(function () {
    let $this = $(this);
    let text = $this.html();
    let mtc = text.toLowerCase()
    if (mtc.match(/^\[itemtext .*\]$/)) {
        let num = shortCode(text, "num");
        let title = shortCode(text, "title");
        $this.text(num + " " + title); //expected output: 1 This
    }
});
```

```css
span {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 3px 10px;
  margin: 3px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">
    <span>[itemText num="1" title="This is a title"]</span>
    <span>itemText num="1" title="This is a title"</span>
</div>
```

Explanation of the regex in `shortCode()`:

- `\\b` -- word boundary to avoid false positives for attributes
- `+ attr +` -- attribute
- `="` -- literal `="` text
- `([^"]*)` -- capture group 1: everything up to and excluding `"`

Explanation of `^\[itemtext .*\]$` regex:

- `^` -- anchor at start of string
- `\[` -- expect `[`
- `itemtext`  -- literal text (includes trailing space)
- `.*` --  greedy scan
- `\]` -- expect `]`
- `$` -- anchor at end of string

Comment: A few issues/limitations: can't have double-quote in the title. `my-title="This is a title"` will be considered the same as `title="This is a title"`

Comment: @MaximMazurok Is there any solution to solve my-title, title issue? it should only work with title not in other name.

Comment: @PriyoGuideline: Do you need `my-title` attribute name too? I can tweak the regex if needed

Comment: @PriyoGuideline I provided these examples to prove the point that it's a much more challenging task with a much greater scope than it might seem at first, so you really should instead seek some ready solutions instead.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using a modern framework such as React, or even AngularJS will do for your case.
Alternatively, I'd suggest using mature templating solutions, like Mustache.
Or to put all the data like so: `<span data-title="my title" />`, etc.
It'll be a nightmare to invent and maintain your custom solution, a lot of regular expressions to parse, to consider edge cases, like spaces or special characters in titles, etc.

But it's holidays time, so here's a code that you asked for:

```js
function shortCode(a, b, c) {
    if (!a.startsWith("[") || !a.endsWith("]")) return;
    a = a.substring(1, a.length - 1);
    var split = a.split(" "),
        regex = /(?<=")\w.*?(?=")/g;
    for (var i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
        var pair = split[i].split("=");
        if (pair[0].trim() == b) {
            c = pair[1];
            if (c.match(regex) != null) {
                return String(c.match(regex)).trim()
            } else {
                return false
            }
        }
    }
    return false
}

$(".test span").each(function () {
    var $this = $(this),
        text = $this.html(),
        mtc = text.toLowerCase(),
        num = shortCode(text, "num"),
        title = shortCode(text, "title");
    if (mtc.match("itemtext")) {
       if (num && title) {
         $this.text(num + " " + title); //expected output: 1This is a title
       }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">
    <span>[itemText num="1" title="This"]</span><br>
    <span>itemText num="2" title="That"</span>
</div>
```

Comment: why shortcode is not working when i put "This is a title" in title?

Comment: @PriyoGuideline it doesn't work in your original code either, because you're doing `split(" ")` so your keys/values can't have spaces in them.

Comment: can you fix this?

Comment: @PriyoGuideline I can, but there are way too many other unknowns and undiscovered problems, so it doesn't make any sense to do this. If you want an easy solution - just put JSON string in span instead of [bla] and parse it using JSON.parse(). That won't be as user-friendly, but you won't have to do all the complicated parsing.